# Problem to create new Entity with javax.persistance

Tags: spring, database

I have the next error when I'm trying to create a new Entity with netBeans, any solution?

[CLICK FOR THE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q35u.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below dependency.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Or else add Spring boot jpa dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```